# Form script clearing textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

I am using the following script to clear fields if a user switched between the forms via a select option drop down:

```
var isFormChanged = false;
$("select").change(function () {
    var type = $(this).val();
if(isFormChanged)
{
 var sure= confirm ('Your changes will be lost, proceed?');
    if(sure)
    {
        $('div.box.active').find('input[type=text]').val('');
        $('div.box.active').find('input[type=radio],[type=checkbox]').prop('checked',false);
       showForm(type);

    }else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
   showForm(type); 

});

function showForm(type)
{
    $('div.box').removeClass('active').hide();

    $('div.box.'+type).show().addClass('active');
    isFormChanged = false;
}

$('div.box').find('input').on('change',function(){
isFormChanged = true;
});
```

It works perfectly fine and clears any select boxes or radio options selected but it will not clear textareas. I am unsure where or how to include these?

Comment: what kind of textarea is it? can you show the markup please?

Comment: There's [`reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset) method available in forms, why not use that?

Answer (score 1):

`textarea` is its own tag. You'll need to grab it directly:

```
$('div.box.active').find("textarea").val('');
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e73y60rt/)